# Ubuntu 14.04 installer not detecting Windows 7 I already have four primary partitions

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, partitioning

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 Trust Tahr and created a bootable USB stick with the .iso image on it. When I choose the USB stick as the boot device it takes me to the Ubuntu installer GUI. However, once it gets to the actual installation step, it says *"This computer currently has no detected operating system"* So I did some searching around and only found some questions that had complicated answers about partitions, etc. Partitions are new to me, and I only have a basic understanding of them.

So could someone please provide a fairly simple answer? I'd really appreciate it. I've been looking forward to getting Ubuntu for a long time and am anxious to get this working. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/107538/12218)

Comment: Choose **Try Ubuntu** and not **Install Ubuntu** after you boot the live dvd. This way you will be able to run a live session and if all goes fine and you get to the live desktop, you can choose to install Ubuntu using the Live installer option. Also, when given those 3 option for installing Ubuntu, choose **Something else**, the third option so you be able to get to your partition table and decide where to install Ubuntu and how much space you want to allocate for the whole installation.

Comment: When I click something else, it comes to a screen showing several different partitions. What exactly do I do here?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-7-using-something-else

Comment: @RodSmith That article was very helpful. Here's what I tried: I went into the Windows 7 disk management and shrunk the C drive, creating 24GB of unallocated space. I then went back into the Ubuntu installer, and selected the "something else" option. Here's where more trouble came, instead of displaying as free space, the 24GB unallocated partition showed up as unusable. What now?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/224927/my-partition-table-is-facing-limitations-having-problems-creating-more-partitio

Comment: I don't exactly see how that topic relates to me. It seems that I've reached my limit of primary partitions. Is there a way to bypass that limit? From my understanding, I should just be able to install Ubuntu onto the 24GB unallocated section I created earlier. As I said, I'm new to partitions so some of this is confusing to me. However, I'd like to learn more and fix this issue so I can get Ubuntu successfully installed on my system. @RodSmith

Comment: Indeed my problem is that I already have four primary partitions. Is the only option left to delete one of those partitions?

Comment: Ok, well I went a deleted an unneeded partition. I then went into Ubuntu installation and clicked the free space, clicked + and created an ext4 partition. However, once I created the ext4 partition, the free space changed back to unusable because the new ext4 was taking up the fourth partition space. Now I don't have any way to create a swap area. I would really appreciate it if someone would reply, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

you may have too many partitions..  Windows 7 'Disk Management' utility is somewhat lacking in its ability to create partitions.

More specifically it will insist on creating 'Primary' partitions and after creating the 4th primary partition it will only allow 'Dynamic' volumes to be created.

However the total number of partitions that can be accessed by Windows 7 is limited only by the number of available drive letters (C to Z) after subtracting the drive letters used by one or more CD/DVD/Blue Ray drives. You must also keep at least one free drive letter available for and external USB drive or flash drive.

Any partitions that do not have a drive letter assigned will be hidden from Windows Explorer.

If you create an 'Extended' partition the you can create addtitional 'Logical drives' however a third perty disk management utility may be the best solution for accomplishing this.