# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Pavillion Issues

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

For the past couple of days I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my Laptop so it can Dual-Boot alongside Windows 7. I have Windows 7 pre-installed with the Laptop.

Firstly I downloaded the ISO File and I installed it on the USB using the instructions on the ubuntu website.

I put the USB in the laptop and then when I restarted it successfully boots and give me a black screen with 4 options the first is to try Ubuntu and the second is to install directly.

For the case which I choose Try Ubuntu and then choose to Install Ubuntu via there, the issue is that it tells me during the installation "**This computer currently has no detected OS. What would you like to do?" and the options are to Erease disk and install ubuntu or something else. When I choose something else it gives me 4 partitions.
sda1,sda2,sda3,sda4.** I didn't know what to do from there.

I tried something else, when the computer restarts I actually pressed F9 and I chose the booting. There were a number of options, but the weird thing is there was the name of the USB that has Ubuntu on it, and the same exact name but with [UEFI] beside it.

When I choose to boot without the UEFI, it took me directly to a menu where I choose to try ubuntu or install ubuntu, using this way, **it gives me another option during the installation which is Install Inside Windows 7, when I choose it, the computer just restarts.**

*I have UEFI off and Legacy on from the settings.*

After googling and going through various forums, I thought the problem would be because HP Laptops come pre installed with 4 partitions. **I have actually deleted HP Tools Partition and it didn't do anything**. Same behavior during the installation.

**I tried to shrink my C driver** and I left 40GB of unallocated space using the Windows Disk Management tool, but it also didn't do anything.

I am out of ideas and out of hope ! I tried lots and lots of tutorials on YouTube and forums but nothing helped me.

Thank you so much for reading this and any help would be so much appreciated !

Comment: First, [determine your Windows 7 boot mode.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#windows) If you boot in EFI mode, then you should disable BIOS/CSM/legacy support; if you're booting in BIOS mode, leave that enabled. If you're using BIOS mode, you may need to [deal with the 4-partition limit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224927/my-partition-table-is-facing-limitations-having-problems-creating-more-partitio) of MBR. You should also learn to use the [Something Else](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223341/install-alongside-windows-or-something-else-which-should-i-use) install option.