# I can't create more than 4 partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I had installed Ubuntu to my Dell Inspiron laptop with 3 partitions.

After I installed Windows I was unable to create new partitions, since I already reached the maximum number of partitions.

So I deleted the Ubuntu partitions and I installed Windows on two partitions. So I have got 4 partitions with Windows.

Then I tried to install the Ubuntu that previously deleted(on unallocated space). But the problem is that unallocated partitions are grayed out and can't be used. 
Now what can I do?

Comment: If you have MBR partition table, you can't have more that 4 primary partitions. You needed to do 1 extended.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for your response. That is the big problem me. How to change the primary partitions in to the logical partitions?

Comment: You can't. You need to remove one of existing partitions, create extended, and then any number of logical in it.

Comment: I made an answer of these comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My partition table is facing limitations; having problems creating more partitions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224927/my-partition-table-is-facing-limitations-having-problems-creating-more-partitio)

Comment: other possible dupe: http://askubuntu.com/q/149821/178596 - all thesesquestions don't really have a consistent answer....

Answer (score 2):

You can not have more that 4 primary partitions on MBR disk.

You need to remove one of the existing partitions and create an extended in it its place.

Then it will be possible to create logical partitions in extended.